# Switching between macro or function

Tags: c, function, macros

I have three files.

1. ass3.c
2. ass3.h
3. teacher.c

*teacher.c* was supplied to me and cannot be changed it in any way and the other two files were coded by me.

*teacher.c* has the main() function and includes *ass3.h*.

*ass3.c* also includes *ass3.h*. *teacher.c* calls for functions in *ass3.c*.

The program works but I need to add another functionality.

I need to add the ability for a user to specify if user wants to use a macro or a function (call it *isAvail()*). Right now the program works only using the *isAvail()* function.

How do I go about implementing this? The excerpt for the requirement is:

"Implement *isAvail()* as a **function** and a macro expansion(macro) using conditional processing, the user can choose between macro or a function in the compiled code. If *IS_AVAIL* (the macro name) name is defined the macro should be used, if the IS_AVAIL name is not defined, the function should be used"

Again, please keep in mind that I can only change Ass3.c and Ass3.h.

Please point me to the right direction and if possible can you please give me an example as well. If I need to add more details please excuse me.

Thank you.

Comment: You could just have a function read from `stdin`, and based on what it finds, use either a macro or a function, though it should be fairly clear which to use...

Comment: @Senri I see this is your first question, did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

Just check if `IS_AVAIL` is defined like this

```
#ifdef IS_AVAIL
#define isAvail() MACRO_DEFINITION_HERE
#else
int isAvail(void) {return ?;}
#endif
```

where `?` is what should be returned by the function.